# Translate animation lag issue, image leaves a tail while translating from one position to another

Tags: android, animation, transition

I translate an image from one position to another, it leaves a tail while image is translated. I have searched a lot on stack overflow and have taken care of heap size, hardware software acceleration, avoiding animation call in oncreate and onresume function. The size of image is also to its minimum.

Any suggestions is highly appreciated.

[image: Here is the image how it looks while transition animation is applied]

Comment: Can you attach images which show your problem...

Comment: please post your code where applying animation?

Comment: tail? what tail? what are you talking about?

Comment: @pskink I have edited my question. You can now get a clear idea what actually is happening while i apply transition animation

Comment: @SagarPatil Are you calling `view.invalidate(Rect)` by yourself? It seems the redraw area is wrong (it should be greater).

Comment: @tato.rodrigo i have tried both options. The image that i have added is while translating. Once the translation is done the image is displayed perfect.

Comment: @SagarPatil Could you share the animation code and also the original image?

Comment: @tato.rodrigo i cannot share the image. But this is what i am trying to do.


TranslateAnimation translationAnim = new TranslateAnimation(0,
    (positionX), 0, (positionY));
  translationAnim.setStartOffset(400);
  translationAnim.setDuration(1000);
  translationAnim.setFillAfter(true);



I am just trying to do a simple translate animation. Its working fine on all many devices except a few devices like Amazon and Samsung  gt-p5210, Samsung Sm-t230nu

Comment: If anyone has a solution, please share it.